# How to check directory exist in remote server using java, when i check i got URI is not absolute

Tags: java

> This is my sample code below,

```
  URI uri=new URI("/192.168.0.135/user-directories/test01/");
     File f=new File(uri);
     System.out.println(""+f.exists());
```

Output is:

```
URI is not absolute
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:361)
```

How to check remote directory exist using File?

Comment: First things first. Do you have the proper permissions to access remote directory?

Comment: Did you try URI `http://192.168.0.135/user-directories/test01/` or `file://192.168.0.135/user-directories/test01/` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your communication is with a FTP Server I this link will help you:
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/determine-if-a-directory-or-file-exists-on-ftp-server

PS: For some reason the website is not allowing me to add a comment so posted in the answer section. Not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: you need 50 reputation to comment. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 0):

Your URI is not absolute. See [RFC 3986 Section 4.3. Absolute URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-27)

Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

> An absolute URI specifies a scheme; a URI that is not absolute is said
> to be relative.

You need to provide a [scheme](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml) like `http`, `ftp` or other.